# How can I show more than 50 services on one page?

Tags: information-architecture

I am currently working on a site that must display more than 50+ government services on a single page, as well as details for each service.

Categorizing them is a not an option because the user needs to go straight to the service with minimal clicks.

How can I accomplish this pleasantly without simply showing a 50-item list?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [how Google organizes their products](https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products/):

> <sub>You may also [view the full resolution, uncropped screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqt1A.jpg) if you'd rather.</sub>
>
> [image: Beautifully cropped screenshot of Google's app organization]

They also have a very large number of products, but they do several things well:

- **Showcase only their most popular products**

  - These are more likely to be what their users are looking for, so begin by presenting the user with these
- **Group their highlighted items by similar functionality**

  - By providing easily scannable categories, a user can more quickly hone into their target
- **Provide the full list of apps, alphabetically, at the bottom**

  - Google still breaks down their full list to group by their target user groups, still catering to their largest user group by expanding their "For all" section by default

Perhaps you could borrow some of these concepts in your design.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a search bar tool.

Assuming that your users are not going to browse all the services and already know which service they want to use, you can simply have them input the service title or content into a search bar at the top of your list of services.

Search bars will allow users to filter the list based on related terms or directly find the service they're looking for by name. You could even have saved recent searches for those users that regularly only use one or two services.

This saves them from scrolling and reading.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. If the search is a typeahead, the result(s) would appear as the user types and they could simply click the service from the results list (without having to actually "submit" the search).

Answer (score 1):

How about something like Yahoo.com from the 90's?

You'd need a modern design obviously, but it was basically showing a lot of options on the home page, arranged into groups.

This seems to fit what you want, especially the "minimal clicks" requirement, which tends to preclude search, etc as options.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you can’t categorize them, but are they sortable with tags? Perhaps there are half a dozen tags that can be broadly applied across the services that are intuitive to your audience, that could be used to sort/filter the services, so that the most pertinent bubble to the top of the page.